# SVN Help, messed up my svn directory

Tags: shell, svn

I was working in a copy of my directory in another server. When I moved it to the one with SVN, where I am supposed to work, it overwrote the original directory. The files that were supposed to have .svn no longer had it. I can't add the files, as it says they are not under version control. I cannot commit anything, I keep getting a "(405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKCOL ".

I tried to fix it by doing svn add --force, but that didn't work. I tried making a copy of the directory and then doing svn mv COPYNAME/ ORIGINALNAME/ and when I tried to commit I got the same error message.

How can I clear out the old svn data on this directory and replace it with the new data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96313/how-can-i-restore-svn-control-if-the-svn-folder-has-been-damaged

Comment: That probably means it's trying to make requests to the special `!svn` urls in the wrong place. Check that `svn info` looks correct.

Answer (score 4):

Do a new checkout. It's your only choice. Then, you can copy files changed from your old working directory to your new one.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was twofold. I had to checkout, and the server was actually down for a while.